# How to authenticate digitalocean spaces objects

Tags: python, amazon-s3, oauth-2.0, digital-ocean

I am using digital ocean spaces to store user files(images, videos, and others). I can access it by using amazon-sdk `boto3`. Tried using oAuth2 authentication to authenticate the user for accessing the private files, but it seems this is not supported. Please suggest a way, so that I can authenticate the specific users for which, he/she is the resource owner.

The documentation is clear in explaining how we can generate authorization header, but in my point of view with this headers, any file with the header can access the resource.

Comment: Have you  tried this... https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/spaces/#authentication

Comment: @Prakash Yes, but in this, we can generate authorization headers but I am looking for a way that can authenticate individual user's resource

Answer (score 0):

Finally, there is an option of using `presigned_uri`

import boto3

```
s3Client = boto3.client('s3')
s3Client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params = {'Bucket': 'www.mybucket.com', 'Key': 'hello.txt'}, ExpiresIn = 100)
```